# How to properly use variables in PHP

Tags: php

Here is the portion of my PHP code that I'm trying to work with:

```
$usersname = $_POST["usersname"];
$usersemail = $_POST["usersemail"];
$usersphone = $_POST["usersphone"];
$mailsubject = "New Customer Quote - Form Submission";
$usersbusiness = $_POST["usersbusiness"];
$userswebsite = $_POST["userswebsite"];
$usersbudget = $_POST["usersbudget"];
$usersmessage = $_POST["usersmessage"];
```

This is specifically what I am trying to change:

```
$mailsubject = "New Customer Quote - Form Submission";
```

I would like to change "Form Submission" to whatever the customer entered as their budget.  Here is that I tried doing but apparently doesn't working:

```
$mailsubject = "New Customer Quote - $_POST["usersbudget"]";
```

I know this is something that's probably extremely simple, I just can't seem to figure out what's happening with it...

Comment: tip: you don't have to reassign POST variables `$usersname = $_POST["usersname"];` just uses more memory for no gain when you can use `$_POST["usersname"]` just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$mailsubject = "New Customer Quote - $_POST["usersbudget"]";
```

should be

```
$mailsubject = "New Customer Quote - ".$_POST["usersbudget"];
```

You need to concatenate.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a "." for **string concatenation** as

```
$mailsubject = "New Customer Quote - " . $_POST["usersbudget"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Its Simple...

Please use

```
$mailsubject = "New Customer Quote - ". $_POST["usersbudget"];
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to concatenation suggested by the other answers, you can use curly braces:

```
$mailsubject = "New Customer Quote - {$_POST['usersbudget']}";
```

Make sure you replace the double quotes with single quotes though; you can't have double quotes inside double quotes the way you have it in your question.

Comment: Hahaha huge quantity of people answering.

Comment: Saw a question that didn't require expert knowledge for once; I just had to jump on it.